# Transforming the value of an object from string to number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, url, react-router

I'm currently trying to convert this URL into an object:
bacon=0&cheese=0&meat=0&salad=1

This is as far as I've got:

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(props.match.params.ingredients);
const entries = urlParams.entries();
const params = Object.fromEntries(entries);
```

I now have this:
{bacon: "0", cheese: "0", meat: "0", salad: "1"}

I need to convert the values to numbers.

I've tried using a loop and iterating through Number() and parseInt() but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map each value to a number before passing to `fromEntries`:

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(props.match.params.ingredients);
const entries = [...urlParams.entries()];
const entriesNumeric = entries.map(([key, value]) => ([key, Number(value)]));
const params = Object.fromEntries(entriesNumeric);
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: TypeError: entries.map is not a function. I had this on many attempts of mine.

Comment: Looks ilke `fromEntries` can take any iterable, not just an array - just turn the `entries()` iterator into an array first

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: `entries()` returns an iterator, so you just need to turn it into an array instead

Comment: Ah. Perfect. Thank you!